# Whats the indentation error in this example program?

Tags: haskell, indentation

I cannot see why there is an indentation error

> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )
>
> main.hs:19:17: parse error on input `case'

Every indentation is set with tabs

Do I need to use spaces instead of tabs?

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

csvFile = endBy line eol
line = sepBy cell (char ',')
cell = many (noneOf ",\n\r")

eol =   try (string "\n\r")
    <|> try (string "\r\n")
    <|> string "\n"
    <|> string "\r"
    <|> fail "Couldn't find EOL"

parseCSV :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
parseCSV input = parse csvFile "(unknown)" input


main =
    do c <- getContents
        case parse csvFile "(stdin)" c of
            Left e -> do putStrLn "Error parsing input:"
                        print e
            Right r -> mapM_ print r
```

Comment: It's highly recommended to switch to spaces.  It just works better with Haskell.  I know people like their tabs, and it's possible to use them in Haskell if you're careful, but most people just default to spaces.

Comment: The use of tabs is not *officially* deprecated, but GHC 7.10 turns on `-fwarn-tabs` by default. Using tabs forces you to either use an editor that shows tabs as having 8 spaces or to make sure every "block" starts on a new line. Other people editing your code are likely to first wonder what's going on and then redo it all with spaces. So just don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code looks exactly the same as it does here, then the problem is that `case` does not line up with `c <- getContents` above it; you need to dedent it by one space.  Also, you will need to indent `print e` by one space to line it up with `putStrLn "Error parsing input:"`.